# How to set password to file using zip command line?

Tags: php, passwords, zip

I am trying to set a password to the file I created. But the code i am using right now doesn't work. Could anyone please help me?

This is my current code:

```
public function download_package_end (){
    $form = $this->getUserData();

    $end = "
</download>";


    file_put_contents('download.xml', $end, FILE_APPEND);
    echo shell_exec(`zip -P pass test.zip download.xml`);
    $files = array(
            'download.xml',
            'script_.xml',

        );

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_name = "test.package";
        if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
            $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }

        foreach($files as $file){
            $zip->addFile($file);
        }
        echo shell_exec(`zip -P pass test.zip $files`);
        $zip->close();


    $DAO = $this->getDAO('DAO');
    return $this->status(0,true,'select.success',$DAO->query('download_package_end',$form));

}
```

Comment: Which part of this has anything to do with gzip?

Comment: you are not mentioning anything about `gzip` in your code. in `gzip` there is no direct password protection. from your code looks like you are using `zip`. what you mean by `doesn't work` are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I know my code doesn't have gzip. What i am showing is the current code i am using to protect my file with a password. But i am looking for a way to protect my file with a password.

Comment: with my code -  echo shell_exec(`zip -P pass test.zip download.xml`); -- i am not getting any error or msgs. But it doesn't protect my file with a password.

Answer (score 2):

You are combining `shell_exec` with backticks, which makes no sense.  Use one or the other -- they are equivalent.  Either:

```
echo shell_exec("zip -P pass test.zip download.xml")
```

or

```
echo `zip -P pass test.zip download.xml`
```

Comment: I tried both, but none of which seems to work. There's still no password for the file I am creating.

Comment: Now at least you should see the output from the zip command.  If you are seeing no output, then it is probably working, making the file somewhere.  Do you know where these files would be created?